# Количество символов в потоке cout

Tags: c++

Хотелось бы сделать, чтобы как с *cin* работало.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int get_file_size(std::istream &cin) {
    return cin.tellg();
}

int get_file_size(std::ostream &cout) {
    return cout.tellp();
}

int main() {
    

    std::string text;
    std::cout << "Input text: ";
    
    std::cin >> text;
    std::cout << "File size: " << get_file_size(std::cin) << "\n";

    getline(std::cin, text);
    std::cout << "File size: " << get_file_size(std::cin) << "\n";

    std::cout << "Tim";
    std::cout << get_file_size(std::cout) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вроде делаю всё также, но на выходе у меня *0*. Не пойму как поправить.

Comment: `cout.tellp` не поддерживается.

Comment: `tellg()/tellp()` на применимы к терминалу. Переадрсуйте ввод-вывод на файлы и посмотрите результат (в  том файле, на который переадресовали stdout)

Comment: @avp `tellg()` вроде работает для `cin`, по крайней мере в студии. А для терминала вообще реально как-нибудь вытащить символы в `cout` ? Ну может быть через `cout.rdbuf()` как-нибудь... А с файлами понял, спасибо!

Comment: Пишите свою диагностику в std::cerr (ели не перенаправлять, то будет на экране)

Comment: @avp, если информация с потока `cout` выводится на экран, то данные с буфера сбрасываются и указатель переходит в начало буфера?

Comment: Это может и очевидно, но до меня только сейчас дошло. Получается функция для размера файла должна принимать только файловый поток, а при создании самого файлового потока помимо дисковых файлов можно и стандартные (cin/cout) потоки присоединить